# How to use DATEPART of the GETDATE as a variable for a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, getdate, datepart

This might be easier than I'm making it, I'm pretty new to SQL.

I have a database with a lot of movies release dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

I'm trying to write a query that would return films released on the current date (MM-DD) in various years.

I've tried using:

```
WHERE ReleaseDate LIKE '%-(DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())-(DATEPART(dd,GETDATE())'
```

But it doesn't return anything.

"WHERE ReleaseDate LIKE '%-06-03'" works but I'd really like to automate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrg!  Don't use `LIKE` with dates.

How about just doing something like this:

```
where DATEPART(month, ReleaseDate) = DATEPART(month(GETDATE()) AND
      DATEPART(day, ReleaseDate) = DATEPART(day, GETDATE())
```

Or, more simply:

```
where month(ReleaseDate) = month(getdate()) and
      day(ReleaseDate) = day(getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating `datapart` etc as a string literal by putting it inside the quotes.

You could use [`concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) to build this string dynamically:

```
WHERE ReleaseDate LIKE CONCAT('%-', 
                              (DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()), 
                              '-', 
                              (DATEPART(dd,GETDATE())
                             )
```